# turn button into ajax loader on click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

```
$(".post-btn").text().html("<img src='../images/loader.gif' />");
```

why this doesn't work? I'm sure I got the right selector because I tried $(".post-btn").text('test') and it work. I want the label of the button become an ajax loader when user click on it.

Answer (score 2):

Like this. without the text()

```
$(".post-btn").html("<img src='../images/loader.gif' />");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to chain functions but chaining works when the previous function returns the initial jQuery Object. For example,

```
$(".post-btn").text('Hello');
```

will return **post-btn** object itself after settings its text to "Hello".

but

```
$(".post-btn").text()
```

will return the text of post-btn instead of itself i.e. "Hello" which is not an object.